# Template includes

Tags: templates, template-redirect

I want to use custom template redirects for urls such as `http://example.com/foo` and `http://example.com/foo/bar`

I'm using `add_rewrite_rule` function for this

```php
add_action('init', function() { 
  add_rewrite_rule( "^foo/([^/]*)/?", 'index.php?foo=1&bar=$matches[1]', 'top' ); 
})
```

Then I set the variables

```php
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'foo'; 
    $vars[] = 'bar';
    return $vars;
}

add_filter('template_include', function($original_template) {
    if(get_query_var('foo')) {
        return '/my-template.php'
    } else {
        return $original_template;
    }
}
```

It works fine for links like http://example.com/foo/bar and in my template I can use bar variable.

```
get_query_var('bar');
```

But http://example.com/foo/ returns the 404 error.

Can I make this link with template redirect too?

Comment: I've formatted your code so it's readable, don't put everything on 1 line, it's very difficult to read! While doing that i saw one of your return statements is missing a `;`

Comment: You are using the wrong hook. There is a difference between template_include and template_redirect. Also, you are not building the correct path for the template.

Comment: @user3135691 Thank You for reply, but this code works, the template path is just an example. I thing the problem is in regexp ^foo/([^/]*)/?, so it works for urls like foo/something but not for just foo/. I was playing around this, but did not succeed